# How to listen scrolling event in a TabLayout Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablayout

I am using TabLayout in my project which might have more than 10 TabItems. Now I wanted to hide an other view when the user scroll the TabLayout.

Note: I am not using any ViewPager.

Comment: you want to hide another tab?

Comment: no. not the tab. some other view.

Comment: tab can be both scrolled and clicked...do u want to hide views for both cases??

Comment: only during scroll

Comment: Did yo get solution ?

Answer (score 4):

Every instance of View calls `getViewTreeObserver()`. You can add an `OnScrollChangedListener()` to it by using `addOnScrollChangedListener()`.

In your case:

```
tabLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(() -> {
        int scrollX = tabLayout.getScrollX(); // Current x scrolling position

        // We know that we have at least one child
        int maxScrollWidth = categoryTabLayout.getChildAt(0).getMeasuredWidth() - windowSize.x;

        // Do whatever you want here
    });
```

windowSize is a Point accessed from the `WindowManager`

```
private Point windowSize = new Point();
// Calculate the position if this window
getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize(windowSize);
```

By using the approach above you will have updates about the proper scroll position you need

Answer (score 1):

TabLayout has its own functionality for tab change listener callback.
Use

**onPageChange Listener:**

```
TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(TabLayout tabLayout)
```

Check this link: [OnTabChange Listener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener.html) for more information

**onTabSelected Listener:**

```
tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener(){
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab){
        int position = tab.getPosition();
    }
});
```

Check for more: [onTabSelected Listener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html#setOnTabSelectedListener(android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using  your TabLayout with a ViewPager like this:

```
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

Then you can use:

```
viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener(){
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset,
                int positionOffsetPixels){
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position){

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state){

        }
    });
```

And in the method onPageSelected(), you can do the action you want depending on the tab showing.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got the solution when your scroll till last tab is visible. Below is the code given. Hope it will help.

```
      val lastTabIndex =  yourTabLayout.tabCount - 1
    val lastTab =  yourTabLayout.getTabAt(lastTabIndex)
   yourTabLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener {
        val scrollX = yourTabLayout.scrollX
        val tabsWidth = yourTabLayout.getChildAt(0).width
        val tabsViewWidth = yourTabLayout.width
        if (scrollX + tabsViewWidth >= tabsWidth) {
            // Tabs are scrolled to the right end
            // You can perform any actions you need here
           

          // Get the last tab and do whatever you need with it
            lastTab?.let {
                //perform the action with last tab
            }
        }else{
           /* Write the code when your are not in last tab position.

             */
        }
    }
```